# Error when testing a web service with client web service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I developed a web service with the  JAX-WS API and now I'm trying to test it with soap ui and other client web service. The problem is when I enter an input, no output figures (I think that it is an encoding problem).

This is snapshots for the client web service [image] and exceptions in my WS [image]

Comment: Your snapshot isn't showing up.

Comment: my account is new , i can't publish snapshot , i need 10 reputations:(

Comment: Put your snapshot in some place like imgur and put the link in hte question.

Comment: this is a link for my snapshot : http://imgur.com/P0eafxz

Comment: Try setting ther arg0 tag value in a CDATA enclosure such as <![CDATA["Select * from b"]]>

Comment: Then show us a code snippet from your WS implementation. Any exceptions around?

Comment: Yes, some exceptions figures  in my WS , i added a snapshot for the exceptions .

Comment: Show us the MyDsl class implementation, specifically the query method.